# Let $N\unlhd G$ and let $K$ be any subgroup of $G$ that contains $N$. Then $K\unlhd G$ iff $K/N\unlhd G/N$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

In Hungerford's *Abstract Algebra*, they state the following Corollary:

> "Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and let $K$ be any subgroup of $G$ that contains N. Then $K$ is normal in $G$ $\iff$ $K/N$ is normal in $G/N$."

In the proof of this corollary, they state that if $a\in G$ and $k\in K$, then the following equation follows from the normality of $K/N$:
$$\tag{1}
N a^{-1} k a=\left(N a^{-1}\right)(N k)(N a)=(N a)^{-1}(N k)(N a) \in K / N
$$
My question is where exactly the "normality" comes in to the picture here? $N a^{-1} k a=\left(N a^{-1}\right)(N k)(N a)$ follows from the definition of the binary operation in the quotient set. I would then assume that $Na^{-1}=(Na)^{-1}$ should follow from normality. But consider
$$\tag{2}
N a \cdot N a^{-1}=N a a^{-1}=N e=N a^{-1} a=N a^{-1} \cdot N a.
$$
This shows that $Na^{-1}$ is the inverse of $Na$ without using normality, so why exactly does eq. $(1)$ require this condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question is, why does $(Na)^{-1}(Nk)(Na)$ belong to $K/N$? That's not a product of $3$ elements of $K/N$, we just conjugated an element of $K/N$ by an element of $G/N$. But that's exactly where the assumption $K/N\trianglelefteq G/N$ is used, it implies that this conjugate indeed belongs to $K/N$.

Comment: More specifically, I am interested in knowing why eq. $(1)$ requires normality? Why would it not be enough that $K/N$ be a (normal or not normal) subgroup of $G/N$?

Comment: @Logi That's what I explained in my answer. If $K/N$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G/N$, the product $(Na)^{-1}(Nk)(Na)$ might not belong to $K/N$. (moreover, for sure there would be some $a,k$ for which it wouldn't belong to $K/N$) A subgroup $N\leq G$ being normal in $G$ means that for all $g\in G$ and $x\in N$ we have $gxg^{-1}\in N$, that's one of the equivalent definitions of normality.

Comment: Sorry, I get it now.

Comment: $N \unlhd G \Leftrightarrow \forall a \in G: a^{-1} N a=\left\{a^{-1} n a \mid n \in N\right\} \subseteq N$

Comment: @Logi Yes, that's right, assuming that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$. That's an important detail. But here $K/N$ is indeed a subgroup of $G/N$, that's easy to check.